# Insert item in panel header just after the title

Tags: extjs

I need to align header item in panel right after the title, like this:

[title][item]============================[<<]

But got this:

[title]============================[item][<<]

I'm using extjs 4.2.1

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
  Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
      width: 500,
      height: 500,
      collapsible: true,
      renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
      header: {
        titlePosition: 0,
        title: "title",
        items: [{
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'test'
        }]
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/U8MSd/152/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could position it with a class. [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1u71)

Answer (score 1):

For version 4.2.1, the title component is hard-coded with a flex of 1 which pushes the other items and tools to the far side. We can intercept its addition to the container and remove the flex and add our own spacing with margin. [ExtJS 4.2.1 Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2iut)

If you need to keep tools or other items to the far side you can add your items wrapped in a container with a flex of 1.

Version 5 introduced Ext.panel.Title class, we can set the title config as an object which is passed to the internal Ext.panel.Title component. We can set the flex to undefined as shown in this [ExtJS 5+ Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2iuv)